# Android Studio - Virtual device launch fails

Tags: android, virtualization, intel, haxm

You might have seen a hundred questions already by the same title so let me just tell you why mine is different:

Here's the error:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

- I've already installed HAXM installer from the sdk manager
- When I actually go to install HAXM, it says that my computer doesn't support virtualization
- True that. I have Intel Pentium E2180
- My hyper -v is already disabled
- My BIOS doesn't have an "enable virtualization" option (which is obvious because my processor doesn't support it)

Since all the solutions on stack overflow revolve around the above mentioned points I decided to post this quesiton as all the mentioned solutions didn't work, which I think is precisely because of me not having a supported processor, which brings me to my question:

Can I still somehow run a virtual device to test my apps? I have a Nexus 7 tab, but I still think testing on a virtual device is more convenient and also I can test more devices if they're virtual..

P.S. I'm running Windows 10 (technical preview) Build 9926.

Comment: I got a similar issue, when I chose a too small memory amount for HAXM. You should provide at least 2GB of memory for HAXM. You can configure this value during setup routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can download and use `ARM images` that do not need hardware virtualization instead of using `x86 system images`. Need to tell you that ARM images will be very slow compared to x86 images.

You can download `ARM image` of respective APIs by selecting this option.

[image: ARM Image Download]

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the emulator you have to use ARM image, because your PC doesn't support HAXM

Create a new AVD(Android Virtual Device) and on creation select image that uses ARM(such as armeabi-v7) so it will be emulated on your PC.

Here's picture of image selection
[image: image of image selection]

If you don't have any arm images installed, you can download one from SDK manager

Comment: Should I install the one that says "ARM EABI v7a System Image" for my android API version (21) specifically

Comment: Ok

I added a picture of the AVD creation suite to guide you further

Comment: Yes. comments are not meant for discussion so please open a chat if you will

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can use Genymotion emulator which is very fast and lightweight

[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: I actually went over genymotion requirements and they don't support computers without virtualization support

Comment: Then you can first install the virtual box and later install the genymotion emulator

Answer (score 0):

It might still work if you launch the emulator from the command line with the `-no-accel` switch:

1. Go to your SDK install directory
2. Go to the tools  folder
3. Open a command/terminal window
4. Type `emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 -no-accel` (replace `Nexus_5X_API_23` with the name of the AVD you've set up in Android Studio / Android Developer Tools)